# filter-by-name-wildcard does not work in Jenkins Job-Builder with git as it is in Jenkins web interface for multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I am trying to setup a multibranch pipeline with Jenkins Job-builder.  everything seems to work fine with the exception of filter by name (with wildcards) according to documentation in https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/project_workflow_multibranch.html?highlight=wipe%20out, I should be able to add the following in scm section,

```html
scm:
   - git:
       url: https://some-url
       credentials_id: some-ID
       filter-by-name-wildcard:
             includes: 'master'
             excludes: 'feature/*'
```

This works on the interface when I run jenkins-jobs from the commandline, the field does not show up in the configure page and jobs for every branch in the repository are created, even-though the above is excluding some branches.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?